docker-compose build for a specific platform
I have a docker-compose.yml file used to build images and push them to the registry.
How to restrict the platform target to not build all the defined platforms?
for instance, I want to build for linux/arm64 only.
docker-compose.yml file is:
services:
  python:
    image: registry.lampi.ai:5000/mytestpython:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      platforms:
        - "linux/amd64"
        - "linux/arm64"

Dockerfile is:
FROM python:3.10

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install prometheus_client

I create a simple builder ofr ARM
docker buildx create --bootstrap --name arm_only --driver=docker-container --platform linux/arm64 ssh://<myhost>

And I build the image:
docker compose build --builder arm_only

but both amd64 and arm64 platforms are built.

I found an ugly way by defining the platforms in the compose file as variables ($platf1 and $platf2).
when I want to restrict the build for a specific platform, I populate the variables with the same value.
